# Posting expressions containing Greek variables in questions on Mathematica.SE

Tags: discussion

I have always have difficulties when posting code samples for equations containing Greek letters.

Greek letters are displayed on *Mathematica*.SE in their full name form and consequently I find the display of equations with Greek letters not very aesthetic. I'm interesting about your tips on how to post Greek letters (without LaTeX) in a nice way.

Can anyone tell me how to copy/paste an expression with greek variables from a *Mathematica* input to a post on *Mathematica*.SE in a nice form?

I'm sorry to post my question here, but I couldn't find anything on this. I believe forum organizers will not be happy if I make another post with *Mathematica* inputs with a bad qualiy. I have seen some posts which have been corrected but I would like to know how.

I would like to improve the quality of my posted code, but I'm still blocked on this point.

Comment: OK Thanks a lot for your help.
I better know the way to do this.
However, I have Chrome on Windows 8 and I find the solution not so easy to install.
For the moment, I install m_toolbar.user.js extension. But, I must do complementary tasks in order to autorize the installation namely to create manifest.json file.
But, how can I do to create this file ? in which editor ?
Thank you for your help

Comment: The extension is indeed a little troublesome for Chrome these days. You can try this site instead: http://steampiano.net/msc/

Comment: I'm using Tampermonkey addon for chrome and it works.

Comment: Related: [How to “Copy as Unicode” from a Notebook?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1137/484)

Comment: What is the next step after having installed Tampermonkey ?

Comment: @Bendesarts, with Tampermonkey installed you should just have to click on the [link to the script](https://github.com/halirutan/SE-Editor-Buttons/raw/master/src/m_toolbar.user.js) and it should offer to install it for you.

Comment: Thank you for your help. The installation has been made now but i still don't have the mathematica complementary buttons.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have made to install Tampermonkey thanks to your link. But, I still don't have the access to the mathematica.buttons. May be it is normal since the mathematica.buttons extension is still in grey in Chrome and moreover Tampermonkey writes for the mathematica .buttons "no @grant header set". May you help me for the next step ? thanks a lot for your help